# Problema al mostrar una imagen de una base de datos mongodb a html con fastapi

Tags: html, python, mongodb, fastapi

Tengo un problema con agregar una imagen de una base de datos a una plantilla html:
He creado una version simplificada código. y mi problema radica en que no se carga la imagen.

[image: muestra de que la imagen no carga]

[image: prueba.py]

[image: html]

A continuacion les muestro mi base de datos:

[image]

Comment: No lo vi mencionado directamente, pero supongo que HtmlResponse no renderiza templates de jinja. Probaste ver que sucede usando [Jinja2Templates y Jinja2Templates.TemplateResponse](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/)?

Comment: Podés ver si el html se renderisó correctamente viendo el código fuente. Verás la opción al final del menú desplegado al hacer clic derecho en la pagina.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.